# поиск общей подстроки в javascript

Tags: javascript

Надо найти общую подстроку переданных строк, вот мой код, но он работает только для букв, а надо еще и для цифр, т.е., чтобы в функцию передавали 1234 12654 12098 и общей строкой выбивалось 12

```js
function sS() {
  let m = arguments[0];
  let list = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i].length < m.length) {
      m = arguments[i];
      list.push(m)
    } else list.push(arguments[i])
  }
  for (let i = m.length; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let p = 0; p <= m.length; p++) {
      let c = m.slice(p, p + i)
      let f = true;
      for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        if (list[j].indexOf(c) >= 0)
          continue;
        f = false;
        break;
      }
      if (f)
        return c
    }
  }
  return "<br/>"
}
var a = sS(1213, 121545, 12456)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: `arguments = [...arguments].map(String);`

Comment: Ну на вскидку можно преобразовать число в строку и искать подстроку